# Weird removable drive

Tags: macos, usb

I have a removable 16gig flash drive from lacie. Everytime i put it into a mac computer that hasn't used that drive before, the files that stood on the drive once but are already deleted from it show up in that computer's trash. I don't know why this is happening but it's annoying.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you trashed the files or not ?

Comment: They where trashed from my own computer a long time ago but they still show up in the other computer's trash.

Comment: Have you emptied the trash on the first computer? and how do they show in the trash on the new one - also what are the full directory names on both computers

Comment: If you don't empty the Trash when the drive is connected, they will stay in the in the invisible `.Trashes` folder on the drive and show up in the Trash on any computer it is connected to. Empty the Trash with the drive connected. Files gone.

Comment: @Mark They just show up in the trash if it's connected to another computer. I also don't know what a directory is.

Comment: @douggro I trashed all the files currently on it and emptied the trash. I will let you know tomorrow if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, trashed files are located on the same device as where they where before.

The Trash bin on OSX shows the trashed files of every storage device that is connected to the Mac.

So you have to trash your files while your drive is connected.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks! ;)

Answer (score -3):

I’ve had two LaCie drives *internally melt* with no warning; don’t put anything on that drive that’s of any value to you or not backed up on another drive made by a more reliable manufacturer.

Comment: So you are saying Lacie isn't reliable?

Comment: Are your drives flash based or HDD based?

Comment: Flash drives are the modern equivalent of floppy disks. You use then to carry data from one place to another, not to store it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, aren't flash drives basically just tiny SSDs? Or do I have this wrong?

Comment: @seaturtle - see https://superuser.com/questions/919058/whats-the-technical-difference-between-a-flash-drive-and-an-ssd